# player with harware aceleration for tcp stream

Tags: webcam, streaming-video, vlc

I am trying to  stream video from a pi to another.I have been success-full in that using gstreamer. Playing the video is another question. I can open the stream using VLC but its rather slow and the pi crashes if I try to go full-screen. I have searched a bit and found out that vlc doesn't have hardware acceleration, so I searched a little bit more but found no other way to play a tcp stream.

O found that omxplayer is the one to go but i don't know if or how i could open my stream in it.

the nearest thing i got was dumping from mplayer to omxplayer.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in [my answer to another question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10532/why-cant-omxplayer-display-streamed-movies-well?lq=1), you can use omxplayer to play both UDP and TCP streams. You mention TCP in your question, and the simplest way to do that is using a named pipe:

```
# on the pi side
mkfifo tcp.stream
nc -l -p 1234 > tcp.stream | omxplayer --live tcp.stream
```

There is also apparently [a patch](https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer/issues/242) you can apply to omxplayer to make it to use tcp instead of udp, but that requires you rebuild omxplayer.